# How script this request token with jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am new with the tool jmeter,
Can you help me script this request please?
Thank you in advance for your assistance

> curl -S -i -k  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:
>   application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   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"

https://my-domain/services

I started the test with http request, but I do not know how to integrate my token to make the call my service?

[image]

i have error :

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-08-14 14:39:59 CEST
Load time: 2998
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1959
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1959
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: my-server
```

Response headers:

```
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Comment: Do you understand what is happening when you execute this command?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your get `Unknown Host` error because the value you are using in "Server Name or IP" cannot be resolved to an IP
2. According to the CURL command you have provided in your question you should add **headers** to your request, however **you are trying to add those values as the parameters**.

So summing up, to resolve your issues, you need to:

1. Specify **proper host name**
2. Add **Header Manager** to your Thread Group
3. Put headers (name and value for each header: `Content-Type`, `Authorization`) there so that your requests will be supplied with the required headers.

Answer (score 1):

Just record it with JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature.

   - From JMeter main menu choose `File -> Template -> Recording` and click `Create`
   - Click HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and press `Start` button
2. Amend your `curl` command to use JMeter as the [proxy](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-proxies.html) like:

   ```
   curl -x localhost:8888 -S -i -k -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJtb2QiOiJhY2....
   ```

Comment: I register my request, it works very well but when I run for the second time it ends with errors.
  I see that jmeter added:
HTTP Authorization Manager (https://rct.devinfo/services $ {AUTH_LOGIN} $ {AUTH_PASSWORD} KERBEROS
HTTP Header Manager:
Content-Type application / json
User-Agent curl / 7.57.0
Accept application / json

where is the pbm?